# Accessing global variables within same file/package

Tags: go

Consider the following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

var global int = 40

func main() {


    var global int = 30
    fmt.Println(::global) // In C++ this would print 40

}
```

How can I print the global variable value 40? There are posts on SO about accessing global variables from different packages but I could not find anything about accessing globals within the same file/package

Comment: The local variable named global shadows the package level variable. You can't access the package level variable if you do this.

Comment: @Peter Thank you.  I know about shadowing and that is the reason i have asked this question. Like i have given example of C++. I am just curious to know whether that sort of thing is possible in Go or not

Comment: At first, reading this made me think that `global` was a new keyword, simply because im not used to seeing long variable declarations!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print the global variable value 40?

By not shadowing it. Or if you absolutely must shadow it (but why would you?), re-assign it to another variable first.

```
func main() {
    originalGlobal := global
    var global int = 30
    fmt.Println(originalGlobal)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not a big fan of shadowing. I am new to Go and I just came across this issue of scope and was wondering if Go provides support for shadowing in the same file or not

Comment: Yes, it supports shadowing.

Comment: But in this case it does not. It does support it for different packages but not in the same file/package

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't in this case? Your example demonstrates shadowing.

Comment: i mean i can declare a var but i am not able to retrieve or use the value of the global variable

Comment: Yeah, that's what shadowing means :)

Comment: Ok so can we say that Go supports Shadowing in the same file but it is of no use if someone wants to access the value of global variable without any "workaround"?

Comment: Go supports shadowing. Period. Shadowing is _only possible_ in the same package, so saying "in the same file/package" doesn't add any information. It doesn't support "unshadowing"--accessing the shadowed variable.

Comment: `originalGlobal` is a copy - so only useful for read purposes. Any changes will not be written back to the global version - nor can they be without taking the address of the global first. But this is all starting to get a little messy...